# Android Studio Maps Not Showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maps, manifest

I'm at home because of the coronavirus's contention and so I'm trying to advance my studies. Right now i have an Android Studio problem creating a Maps APP. The APP needs to find a location by Latitude and Longitude, also a city by name and locate your location with a floatingactionbutton. The code was working perfectly, when I added the code to locate your location, the map wasn't showing anymore. It loads with no error, but the map doesn't work.

[Maps Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDUto.png)

Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pt3_googlemaps_filipetto_patricio">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAHwtaI8O698ZSeVM8Y4xvjRXxAYi9Kr38" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also attach the dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What have you added that broke the code? It could be an issue about google api permissions on your KEY.

Answer (score 0):

i added this, when i click the button find my location and moves to it.

```
 FloatingActionButton myUBICATION = findViewById(R.id.myUBICATION);
        myUBICATION.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mMap != null){
                    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {

                            LatLng GPS = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(GPS).title("Marker my ubication"));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(GPS, 10));
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```